# (Resolved)How does the html button tag work with Django template?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

This is a Django template where the user submits some data through a django form to create a new "topic". I want to ask why does the html button work and submit the data I want even though I didn't specify it's type (submit, reset, or button)?

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action ="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button>Add Topic</button>   <comment><-- why does this button still work?</comment>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Heres the views.py, if you need it.

```
def new_topic(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        form = TopicForm(data = request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('learning_logs:topic')
    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html',context)
```

Answered by Abdul Aziz Barkat and Ben ( thanks to them)

Comment: The default type of a button is a submit button (except internet explorer). It has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: By default, button elements in forms are submit buttons. "The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state." https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks. So its type is submit by default as long as its nested in forms tag?